# Can I generate x509 certificate with negative RSA key modulus?

Tags: go, openssl, rsa, x509certificate, modulo

So far I tried to generate x509 certificate in Go, using `x509` library, but this doesn't succeed, since Go doesn't allow to generate negative modulus.

I tried to use `openssl`:

```
openssl req  -nodes -new -x509  -keyout server.key -out server.cert
```

But it generate positive modulus RSA key.
For education purposes I still need negative RSA modulus, is it somehow possible using `openssl`?

Comment: If this is for educational purposes, is the point to learn _how_ to implement the key generation? If you want to use an existing implementation, I would just take the Go source and modify it so it can work with a negative modulus.

Comment: @JimB yeah seems that no standard tools for that and of manual work needed, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: All RSA standards since forever require positive modulus, and all implementations either won't work at all or will work wrong for a negative one. Are you really being taught to harm and endanger people? If so I don't want you in any society I'm in. (Note ASN.1 DER, the encoding for X.509 certs and many other things, does allow negative numbers _in general_ which is why RSA moduli, almost always chosen with bitlength a multiple of 8, encode with an 'extra' zero/sign byte; see https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129490 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30608/ .)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Even more fundamental:  there are no negative prime numbers, and an RSA modulus is the product of prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

An RSA key with a negative modulus is not an RSA key.

Per [RFC 8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-3.1) (bolding mine):

> 3.1.  RSA Public Key
>
> For the purposes of this document, an RSA public key consists of
> two    components:
>
> ```
>      n        the RSA modulus, a positive integer
>      e        the RSA public exponent, a positive integer
> ```
>
> **In a valid RSA public key, the RSA modulus n is a product of u
> distinct odd primes** r_i, i = 1, 2, ..., u, where u >= 2, and the RSA
> public exponent e is an integer between 3 and n - 1 satisfying
> GCD(e,\lambda(n)) = 1, where \lambda(n) = LCM(r_1 - 1, ..., r_u - 1).
> By convention, the first two primes r_1 and r_2 may also be denoted p
> and q, respectively.
>
> . . .
>
> 3.2.  RSA Private Key
>
> For the purposes of this document, an RSA private key may have
> either    of two representations.
>
> 1. The first representation consists of the pair (n, d), where the
>    components have the following meanings:
>
>    ```
>     n       the RSA modulus, a positive integer
>     d       the RSA private exponent, a positive integer
>    ```
> 2. The second representation consists of a quintuple (p, q, dP, dQ,
>    qInv) and a (possibly empty) sequence of triplets (r_i, d_i,
>    t_i), i = 3, ..., u, one for each prime not in the quintuple,
>    where the components have the following meanings:
>
>    ```
>     p      the first factor, a positive integer
>     q      the second factor, a positive integer
>     dP     the first factor's CRT exponent, a positive integer
>     dQ     the second factor's CRT exponent, a positive integer
>     qInv   the (first) CRT coefficient, a positive integer
>     r_i    the i-th factor, a positive integer
>     d_i    the i-th factor's CRT exponent, a positive integer
>     t_i    the i-th factor's CRT coefficient, a positive integer
>    ```

All values by specification are positive integers, and the modulus is the product of two or more [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number).

And all [prime numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) are defined as:

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers.

Any product of prime numbers therefore must also be greater than zero, making a negative modulus for an RSA key mathematically impossible.